# Yugoslav style piano

Tags: theory, piano, technique

Can someone describe what that style is? What are the characteristics? Why does this style exist? Does it lead/can be used as a platform to other things?

Comment: Where have you seen the phrase "Yugoslav style" before"

Comment: In Bela Bartok works of Mikrokosmos

Comment: @Todd - that's probably worth writing up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's just a name Bartok used (in *Mikrokosmos*), it's not a widely accepted piano playing style. My guess is that he wrote in a way that sounded like Yugoslavian folk music, which is why he named it that. Note that there are also pieces in *Mikrokosmos* that are "in a Hungarian style", but that doesn't mean there is a Hungarian style of piano playing.